# encodeURI doesn't escape `equals` - why?

Tags: javascript, http

I have an URI like that:

```
http://client.dev/dap/module/hdfs-web/api/v1.0/clusters/Cluster%201%20-%20CDH4?operation=copy&to=/user/hdfs/year=2016/partial.txt&overwrite=true
```

I use `encodeURI` function to escape string. I'm wondering why spaces are encoded with `%20` while `equals` characters are not?

Comment: Because `=` is a proper URI character?

Comment: `=` has a meaning in URIs - it connects `keys` to `values`, the space character does not, it is simply a bit of string to make it easier for us humans to distinguish words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`encodeURI` encodes a full URI, and URIs can contain `=` characters. For instance, if a user types in a URI, a first step to resolve it would be to call `encodeURI` on it.

If on the other hand you are the one constructing the URI, and the input just determines one field (for instance a search query, when given `E=mc²` you want to resolve `https://www.google.com/search?q=E%3Dmc%C2%B2`), then you are not encoding a full URI, but a URI *component*. Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for that:

```
> encodeURIComponent('= ')
'%3D%20'
```

Comment: thanks, could you please expand a little bit about when `encodeURI` and when `encodeURIComponent` should be used? And also what are the implications of blindly replacing `encodeURI` with `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: I have updated the answer. If you use `encodeURIComponent` to encode a full URI, that will break for a lot of inputs, so you cannot blindly replace it.

Answer (score 3):

The `encodeURI()` function is used to encode a URI.

This function encodes special characters, except:`, / ? : @ & = + $ #` (Use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode these characters).

Tip: Use the `decodeURI()` function to decode an encoded URI.

SOURCE: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp)